# How to setup email alerts in snowflake

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Is there any way we can send email alerts from snowflake if warehouse reaches its limit or if any query is blocked.

saw many videos where we can setup email framework using python and .NET but anyone tried this in snowflake ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of External Functions, AWS SES and Lambda Functions. With the External Function you can trigger Lambda, which is sending the mails via SES.

Solution design: https://medium.com/hashmapinc/sending-email-notifications-from-snowflake-using-external-functions-4b985c182292

External Functions: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake natively does not have the option for this kind of mechanism but usually leverages the cloud features for the alert operations.

OOTB alerts are limited to the Resource monitors as detailed here: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/resource-monitors.html

For Snowpipe there is notification mechanism as detailed here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-errors.html